# TYPO3 Service Unavailable (503) standard error after installing existing project

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, typo3-8.x

I installed a copy of a TYPO3 project.
So, I'm using an existing TYPO3 database.

When running the home page of the site, I get the 'standard error':

```
Service Unavailable (503)
The page is not configured! [type=0][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=0 configured.
More information regarding this error might be available online.
```

which refers to following site:
https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1294587217

But when I modify the setup of the template of the root as given in the link. I get an empty page with "HELLO WORLD" and the whole website is gone.

The old root setup code was:

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
page.meta.description.data = page:description
page.meta.keywords.data = page:keywords
```

How can I solve this problem without losing the rest of the website?
Using TYPO3 8.7

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the copied database, did you also copy all installed extensions in directory `typo3conf/ext/`? And are these extensions active in your Extension Manager?

It is possible that your website templates and configurations were stored in a custom extension and were then included as a so-called *Static Template*.

1. Copy the needed extension(s), if not yet available in your website copy.
2. Activate the extensions in the backend module `ADMIN TOOLS > Extensions`.
3. Include the Static TypoScript templates in your root TypoScript record: tab *Includes*, field *Include static (from extensions)*.

---

To **activate** an extension, click the button on the left of your extension list (box symbol with plus sign).

Also, *updating* an extension in the Extension Manager will only work for **public extensions** in the TYPO3 Extension Repository, e.g. a news system. Your template extension (a so-called Sitepackage) will only be stored locally.

[Read here more about Sitepackages in TYPO3.](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/)

Comment: Possibly the answer that you re looking for. +1

Comment: I added the 2 folders to the ext/ folder. (contentelements & contentapi) structure is: ext/ah_contentelements and ext/contentapi (both folders with the files).

Comment: I don't know how to make them active in EM?

Comment: I also changed the PackageStates.php file.. and went to admin tools -> extensions and checked for updates for the EM

Comment: @belgiums under the A/D column you will find the buttons to add or uninstall the extensions. (admintools -> extensions)

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas yes, the 2 are listed and the A/D column gives me the option to deactivate them.. still same error..

Comment: @belgiums after you activated the extensions, you should got to your root page. Then select the template module->edit the whole template record->includes and include the static templates. You can find all these options under info/modify  on your upper left corner, the dropdown field

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying you copied a TYPO3 project, that means that it already has a TypoScript configuration. You will have to find where it is defined and edit the paths accordingly.

If you are using **TYPO3v9** then you should include the path to your TypoScript configuration with the following:

**If you are using an own extension (Edit the path to the actual Typoscript configuration):**

```
@import 'EXT:your_extension_base/Configuration/TypoScript/Setup.typoscript'
```

**If the TypoScript takes place on the fileadmin (Edit the path to the actual Typoscript configuration):**

```
@import 'fileadmin/Files/Configuration/TypoScript/Setup.typoscript'
```

If you are using **TYPO3 v7 - v8 - v9** you can include your TypoScript like this:

**If you are using an own extension (Edit the path to the actual Typoscript configuration):**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:my_extension/Configuration/TypoScript/user.ts>
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:EXT:my_extension/Configuration/TypoScript" extensions="typoscript">
```

**If the TypoScript takes place on the fileadmin (Edit the path to the actual Typoscript configuration):**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:fileadmin/templates/" extensions="ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:fileadmin/templates/" extensions="typoscript">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/html/mainmenu_typoscript.txt">
```

The extension `.typoscript` it is supported from TYPO3 8 and up.

Like @sebklin suggested, since there is not such line as I posted in the old TYPO3 installation, then the configuration is indeed in a custom extension. Just copy / download the extension from the other TYPO3 installation and include the static templates. By including those templates you say to TYPO3 that it should take the  extension’s TypoScript into consideration.

+1 to @sebklin ‘s answer. That is something that a lot of people fail to check when something like that happens.