# TYPO3 Service Unavailable (503)

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I installed a copy of a TYPO3 project. So, I'm using an existing TYPO3 database.

When running the home page of the site, I get the 'standard error':

Service Unavailable (503)
The page is not configured! [type=0][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=0 configured.
More information regarding this error might be available online.
which refers to following site: https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1294587217

But when I modify the setup of the template of the root as given in the link. I get an empty page with "HELLO WORLD" and the whole website is gone.

The old root setup code was:

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
page.meta.description.data = page:description
page.meta.keywords.data = page:keywords
```

How can I solve this problem without losing the rest of the website? Using TYPO3 8.7

Addition to the db install I also copied the extension folders to the typo3conf/ext folder and edited the PackageStates.php with the path to the extensions.

I see the extensions in the extensions tab the status is 'local'.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. You already had answers for your original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56599304/typo3-service-unavailable-503-standard-error-after-installing-existing-project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3 Service Unavailable (503) standard error after installing existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56599304/typo3-service-unavailable-503-standard-error-after-installing-existing-project)

Comment: Instead of create a duplicate question with further information, you can add additional information to your existing question

Answer (score 0):

1st: make sure you have the correct configuration of all domains (as it is a copy it can not run with the same domain, otherwise you will switch between servers unpredictably.

2nd: enter list mode and look for multiple `template` records in your web root page. Multiple records will result in ignoring all but one record. maybe you just edit the wrong one. Normally the content is not lost but only inaccessible for the moment.

3rd: have you activated all the extensions which are active in the source installation? especially any site extension, which probably include the configuration for the TypoScript `page` object.

4th: you can use the TSOB (TypoScript Object Browser) and the template analyzer to view the active or resulting typoscript.